# Python error in VSCode :Sorry, something went wrong activating IntelliCode support for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, runtime-error

My code is not working in vscode when i click to run code i saw this error:

> Sorry, something went wrong activating IntelliCode support for Python.
> Please check the "Python" and "VS IntelliCode" output windows for
> details.

and when i try to run code again i saw this message;

> Code is already running

Code dont stop when i click to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> so i have to close the editor and open it back. I dont understand why this happen , please help me,thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your code running inside of threads?

Comment: no ,it is simple code @thethiny

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just like to add a few helpful links:

[Intellicode Issue 57](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/issues/57)

[Intellicode Issue 266](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/issues/266)

[Gitmemory issue 486082039](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/57/486082039)

For a lot of people, it just began working after a few tries randomly. See this text (quoted from issue 57):

> There's a race condition in the activation of both the IntelliCode and Python language server extensions. Even if the Python extension is loaded, the language server that the extension spins up might not be fully initialized yet. So if the Python extension loads, then the IntelliCode extension, then the Python language server initializes, we will have this problem.

For some people, it was working to reload VS Intellicode pack following the reinstall the Python extension pack.

Thank you.

Comment: I just reinstalled python extension and reloaded and it worked.

Comment: In the extensions menu was already a reload button under python. Clicking it fixed the issue for me :)

Answer (score 1):

- First of all find your Python installation path
- Copy it

Then in VSCode

1. Open settings
2. Extensions
3. Python
4. Default Interpreter Path

And paste the full path to your Python installation folder.
For example:

```
X:/Program Files/Python310
```

If it didn't work immediately, try reloading VSCode.

(P.S. Should work without any reloads)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Extensions, then search for the Python extension, then switch to release.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using code-insiders and all python extenstions suddenly started failing. Thanks Hossein.

Comment: I just reinstalled python extension and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to have Pylance installed (intellisense support for Python)
2. Make sure to be into the tab for any python file For VS Code, and locate the `{} Python` icon on the bottom row. Click over the **{}** icon, and then click over **Select Interpreter**. Just after that, make sure to input the desired python path, wait for a few seconds in the current python tab, and finally Pylance will be doing its job